# [Zapier + WP Webhooks Pro]: Custom Fields get cut off at first comma or semicolon

Tags: rest-api, api

I'm using Zapier and [WP Webhooks Pro](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-webhooks/) to connect Google Sheet and WP to auto-publish posts for each row added to the spreadsheet.

It works like as expected and all fields, including custom fields, are populated correctly expect those that have a string with a comma and/or semicolon. Those get cut off.

**Setting up the custom field in Zapier**
[image: Setting up the custom field in Zapier]

**Success output in Zapier after posting to WP**
[image: Success output in Zapier after posting to WP]

**Custom field in WP (cut off after semicolon)**
[image: Custom field in WP]

Any help/direction on how to fix this issue would so much appreciated.

Comment: Please note that 3rd party plugins, such as WP Webhooks Pro, are considered off-topic here on WPSE. Should you have any questions regarding the setup, usage or customization of a 3rd party plugin, please contact the plugin author for support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WP Webhooks Pro also accepts JSON constructs for more complex strings.
Here's an example of how your **meta_input** can look like:

```
{"meta_key":"data:image/png;base64,iVBOR......."}
```

Simply paste that within your Zap and change the **data:image/png;bse64,iVBOR.......** to your dynamic value. :)

Comment: Cheers Jannis! I actually did try this yesterday as well but for some reason it didn't work for me. However, gave it another shot and now it does work! Might have had tired eyes. Thanks again!